# apacite - truncate citation call-outs with "et al" for 5 or more authors

Tags: citing, apacite

The instruction `\citeA` of the `apacite` package is set to truncate citation call-outs -- using `et al` -- for entries that have 6 or more authors. However, I want to use `et al` for citation call-outs for all entries with 5 or more authors. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `apacite.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say `apacite-mod.bst`. (Don't edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `apacite-mod.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- Locate the function `tentative.cite.num.names.field` in the bst file. (In my copy of the file, the function starts on line 814.) In this function, locate the line that says

  ```
      { numnames #6 <
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
      { numnames #5 <
  ```
- For good housekeeping, make two further changes. First, a few lines down from "`{ numnames #5 <`", change the string "`% 3-5 names`" to "`% 3-4 names`". Second, a few more lines down again, change "`% 6 or more names`" to "`% 5 or more names`".
- Save the file `apacite-mod.bst`, either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by your TeX distribution. If you choose the latter method, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` to `\bibliographystyle{apacite-mod}` and do a full recompile (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more).

Happy BibTeXing!

A full MWE -- observe that APA6 style is to use "et al" from the second citation onwards for entries with *3 or more* authors:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{4,author="A and B and C and D", title="X", year=3001}
@misc{5,author="A and B and C and D and E", title="Y", year=3002}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite-mod}
\begin{document}
\citeA{4}, \citeA{4}

\citeA{5}, \citeA{5}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```